# Windows7 WAMP 64-bit stack MySQL problems

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, 64-bit

By using this guide here ->
http://www.elxis.org/guides/developers-guides/64bit-apache-php-mysql-windows.html

And hacking through the errors and issues that came up, I've got an apache, php, and MySQL stack almost working on Windows 7 - all 64 bit. PHP and apache are working just fine, and phpinfo tells me that mysql support is enabled.

Now here's the problem. Any php script that actually *calls* MySQL gives me a "connection reset" error.

I've tried turning off my firewall; it made no difference. I've tried putting libmysql and php_mysql copies in a few different places, including apache\bin and Windows\system32, to no avail.

This is what phpinfo tells me:

```
mysql
MySQL Support enabled
Active Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0
Client API version  5.1.44

Directive Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent On On
mysql.connect_timeout 60 60
mysql.default_host localhost localhost
mysql.default_password no value no value
mysql.default_port 3306 3306
mysql.default_socket no value no value
mysql.default_user no value no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode Off Off
```

MySQL is on, and clearly it's being sensed by php; when I turn it off, phpmyadmin pitches a fit. When it's on however, and I try logging in with phpmyadmin, I get a 'connection reset' error: The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

My error logs are telling me nothing. Nada. Zip. Just that services have been turned on or off, etc., etc.

Anybody know how I can get PHPmyadmin and other mysql connection scripts working??

Comment: I mean, anybody know how I can get the experimental 64-bit stack working. I know I can get 32-bit apache+php talking to mysql, and I know that there are no official distros for php and apache 64-bit; but if anybody's tried this 64 bit configuration and found a solution, that'd be awesomely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP interpreters are available on both 32-bit and 64-bit  operating systems, but on Microsoft Windows the only official distribution is a 32-bit implementation, requiring Windows 32-bit compatibility mode while using Internet Information Services (IIS) on a 64-bit Windows platform. As of PHP 5.3.0, experimental 64-bit versions are available for MS Windows.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/releasenotes

The problem is there is no Official 64 Bit version for Windows yet, try the 32 bit version as this should solve your problem.

Comment: I know I can get 32-bit wamp working on my system (except for mysql, which has to be 64 no matter what or it hangs) but I'm being experimental. It hit the limits of what I could do, and so I came here to share the problem. :P

Comment: Why does MySQL need to be 64 Bit?