# How do I debug errors that have no error message?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, debugging

How do I debug errors that have no error message?

When loading a PHP page I am getting this error in Firefox.

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

It gives no indication as to why other than it appears to be Apache crashing.

Apache error logs shows:

```
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:04 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:06 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:06 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:06 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:06 2010] [notice] Server built: Nov 11 2009 14:29:03
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:06 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5100
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Child 5100: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Child 5100: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Child 5100: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Child 5100: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 03 10:23:07 2010] [notice] Child 5100: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I tried searching the 3221225477 code but found nothing that worked.

Also the Windows Event Viewer shows this:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.14.0, time stamp: 0x4aeb9704
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.3.1.0, time stamp: 0x4b06c41d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00082391
Faulting process id: 0x8f4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb7b85fa74bf83
Faulting application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\xampp\php\php5ts.dll
Report Id: 73996201-e779-11df-938f-e0cb4e5b154a
```

This is happening when I call:

```
return mysql_fetch_object($result, $class_name);
```

Its also happening on another page when I use `$_SESSION`

If I switch to using CGI instead of the `php5ts.dll` and `php5apache2_2.dll` I get:

```
Premature end of script headers: php-cgi.exe
```

Its is only happening for some pages. Others work fine.

- No PHP errors or exceptions occur. Error reporting is set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`. `display_errors` is on.
- Timeout is set to 60 seconds, the error page is returned in about 10 seconds.
- The memory usage gets about 16MB, the maximum limit is 256MB.
- PHP 5.3.1, Windows 7 64bit.

So does anyone know how to effectively debug this error?

Comment: Same thing is happening when I switched to MySQLi

Comment: Have you tried switching between (f)cgi/mod_php options? And between a PHP 5.2.* vs 5.3.* and possibly other versions? Searching for `php 0xc0000005` mostly shows things related to versions and module types.

Comment: @battal, I cannot use PHP 5.2 as my website needs 5.3 features. I couldn't get an updated version of PHP 5.3 running. (Im using XAMPP) Ill have a look at the CGI stuff tomorrow. Right now Im trying to switch to ISS instead :O

Comment: @battal, when I run PHP through CGI I get `Premature end of script headers: php-cgi.exe` instead

Comment: @battal, upgrading XAMPP seemed to have worked.

Comment: @Petah: Are you using 32 bit PHP or 64 bit PHP?  It seems that the 64 bit version is not ready for prime time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379407/windows7-wamp-64-bit-stack-mysql-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can start by reading ["Generating a Backtrace"](http://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace-win32.php) and searching for registered PHP bug reports similar to you, and submitting a bug if you've really found none. If you are really interested, you can inspect the [PHP Source](http://svn.php.net/) and propose a patch.

Comment: Add some links in and you will get the tick

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are experiencing a bug in PHP, leading to a crash. Try to upgrade to the latest nightly build (http://snaps.php.net/). If that doesn't help, try to [get a backtrace](http://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace-win32.php) and submit a bug on bugs.php.net.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the script is taking a long time to execute so the browser is timing out.  try using the php function set_time_limit to keep the script from dying.

`set_time_limit(0); // no time limit`

Comment: The time limit is set to 60 seconds. The error pages is returned in about 10 seconds.

Comment: Is this a development machine?  If so try installing xdebug or zend_debugger. You can then set breakpoints to find out when its dying

Comment: I know when it is dieing. One one page it dies on a `mysql_fetch_object($result, $class_name)` call, on another page it dies on a `$_SESSION['bla'] = 'bla'` call

Answer (score 0):

If apache is crashing it may be due to a mangled .htaccess. Is there any log entry before the error message/crash to indicate what Apache thought it was doing?

Comment: There are no log entries before that one.

Comment: Correlate the time of error with the entry in apache's activity (non-error) log to see what it was trying to process at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your PHP.

(This is what I did, and now it seems to work, however my question still stands: How do I effectively debug issues like these?)

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.php.net/bugs-getting-valgrind-log.php

[edit2]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace can also be handy to find the spot that takes you system down.

[edit]
how did you monitor the memory usage?

Comment: Printing out `memory_get_usage()` and `memory_get_usage_peak()` after each loop.

Comment: Have you used the real_usage argument? If not, memory_get_usage() will only report the memory used by php itself and not other applications like mysql.